# Error when I'm Trying to send an Email without INTENT sending by Emulator

Tags: android, gmail

I'm tying to send an Email[NO INTENT] to a user using EMULATOR. I tried but I have an error which i cant understand it..I used some code which I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)...I putted all the Jar file but still giving me an error

//  And I'm getting an ERRORS in LOGCAT

05-31 12:12:51.403: V/TLINE(1030): new: android.text.TextLine@40653b20
05-31 12:12:51.953: V/TLINE(1030): new: android.text.TextLine@40656270
05-31 12:13:00.923: I/dalvikvm(1030): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 502 'Lmyjava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;

Comment: did you put jars to **/libs/** folder ?

Comment: I did 3 of them :( but I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 502 'Lmyjava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;
```

This is due to an unsatisfied dependency of your jars. You will need to find this dependency jar.

Try getting some more info from here.

http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/